# PhoneGap globalization.dateToString: why do I get an error?

Tags: javascript, cordova, globalization

I am trying to represent a date using the locale and language of the user.

I use `globalization.dateToString,`, but I get an error (the error callback gets called).

The problem it's not the date, I tried this way and I got again "Error getting dateString"

The exception I get is `undefined`

```
 try {var strTitle=navigator.globalization.dateToString(
            //dtStartTime,
            new Date(),  
            function (date) {alert('date:' + date.value + '\n');},
              function () {alert('Error getting dateString\n');},
              {formatLength:'full', selector:'date and time'}
            );}
    catch(err) {
        alert( err.message);
    }
```

Comment: which version of phonegap/cordova are you using? If you are using cordova above 3.x than you need to add the plugin manually. e.g `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.globalization`

Comment: @frank thanks frank, it's version 2.8.1

Comment: @frank thanks frank, it's version 2.8.1 and indeed it works, the callback is called, but it's the exception callback, I assume there must be something wrong with the Date

Comment: can you check by putting an alert or a console.log call **after** the assignment `var dtStartTime = new Date(strStartTime);` e.g `alert(dtStartTime)` to check whether the date is correct. Also in the error callback can you add a parameter to check what is the error code. The error callback is passed the object `GlobalizationError` as a parameter type.

Comment: @frank thanks Frank I tried, the dtStartTime comes out just fine as a date

Comment: you can add the following code in the error callback and check what is the output. `function (err) {alert("Error code:"+err.code+":Message:"+err.message);}`. Do let us know what is the output?

Comment: @frank thanks Frank I will try now

Comment: @frank `Error code:undefined:Message:undefined`  :-(((((

Comment: are you testing it in the real device? Some occasions the API, do not work on the emulator but do work in the real device.

Comment: @frank Hi Frank, I am using a real device